# Reformat date in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date

I have a problem. I've a date input on my site. When the input type date is not supported by the browser, I'm initializing a jQuery datepicker.

The problem is, that the normal date input returns the value like this:

```
2019-08-23
```

And the datepicker this way:

```
26.08.2019
```

Instead adding a hidden field in the HTML, I want to re-format the received value via PHP to the first format above. So is there a way to build a small function that checks if the format is the datepicker format and which returns the formatted value like `2019-08-26`?

I'm receiving the value with `$_POST['date']`.

Comment: which datepicker are you using?

Comment: jQuery datepicker. I know that there is a solution done in the browser with a hidden input which contains the right value but in my case this is much more work than doing a re-formit in PHP.

Comment: Check the datepicker documentation, they usually provide a way to change the format, for instance this is for [jQueryUI](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: `'2019.08.23'.split('.').reverse().join('-')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

> echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("26.08.2019"));

Reference: [PHP strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)